# how Get current logged in username in Spring Security with jsf?

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-security

I'm new at Spring Security. I'm using jsf2 with spring security 3. Three questions:

How can I access, from a session component, the user info (name,password,roles,last access) of the user currently logged in?

In order to use it in a view, for example for rendering elements depending on the roles of the user.

How can I know if a user is logged in? In order to show in a view a "login link" if the user is not logged in, or a "logout link" if the user is logged in. Which property of Spring Security do I have to use in my component to store this info and use it in the view?

this is my `Authentification` Component

```
@Scope("session")
@Component("Authentification")

public class Authentification {

String username;
public String loggedName() throws IOException,ServletException{
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
      username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
    } else {
       username = principal.toString();
    }
    return username;
}

}
```

and this the call of this method in my xhtml file:
        
all worked fine but when i try to get current logged username i have this error

```
Infos: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
juin 10, 2014 3:36:33 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
Grave: Error Rendering View[/boo/listProjets.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /boo/myDatatable.xhtml @286,68 value="#{Authentification.loggedName()}": Method not found: class $Proxy8.loggedName()
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:178)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:164)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:75)
    at org.primefaces.component.outputlabel.OutputLabelRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputLabelRenderer.java:37)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:389)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own interceptor of every request, which will put into model and view object model of logged user or anonymous or anything else. That's good way if u always need get logged user in view, but if u want to get it at once, one controller/page - better do it in concrete method. Write way it is get SecurityContext and call method getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal() which gives you logged user.  Your code doesn't work because your method which u re try to call is not static and it is good, because that's not good way to get authenticated user from view.

I were in underground, so i could not add some code snippets. There are.
Method to get logged user:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

Full method which implement UserInterceptor:

```
@Component
public class UserInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object o) throws Exception {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object o, ModelAndView mav)
            throws Exception {
        if (mav != null) {
            SmartUserDetails user = (SmartUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            SmartUser smartUser = user.getSmartUser();
            mav.addObject("smartUser", smartUser);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object o, Exception e)
        throws Exception {

    }
}
```

I cast getting logged user to my custom model.

Answer (score 0):

Get the User via a Custom Interface.

To fully leverage the Spring dependency injection and be able to retrieve the authentication everywhere, not just in `@Controller` beans, you need to hide the static access behind a simple facade:

```
public interface IAuthenticationFacade {
    Authentication getAuthentication();
}

@Component
public class AuthenticationFacade implements IAuthenticationFacade {

    @Override
    public Authentication getAuthentication() {
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    }
}
```

The facade exposes the Authentication object while hiding the static state and keeping the code decoupled and fully testable:

```
@Controller
public class SecurityController {

    @Autowired
    private IAuthenticationFacade authenticationFacade;

    public String currentUserNameSimple() {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationFacade.getAuthentication();
        return authentication.getName();
    }
}
```

And if you need to access directly from jsf:

```
<label>#{authenticationFacade.authentication.name}</label>
```